# Developing desktop software from HTML/CSS/JS core

Tags: software-development, javascript, html, css

I spend a great deal of my time developing web content that ends up packaged to mobile devices using Phonegap.

I was wondering if a similar product exists for packaging HTML5/CSS3/JS web apps to work as native apps on desktops?

Whether under OS X or Windows (ideally, a multi-platform solution would be best!).

Comment: You might take a look at QT QML, 'a CSS & JavaScript like language' http://qt-project.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several cross-platform, open-source HTML/CSS/JS desktop
frameworks available.  The most popular, in descending order:

## **[Electron](https://electron.atom.io/)**

[image: GitHub stars]

"The Electron framework lets you write cross-platform desktop applications
using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. It is based on [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)
and [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org) and is used by the
[Atom editor](https://github.com/atom/atom) and many other
[apps](https://electron.atom.io/apps)."

- Actively developed by GitHub

---

## [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/)

[image: GitHub stars]

"NW.js (previously known as node-webkit) lets you call all Node.js modules
directly from DOM and enables a new way of writing applications with all
Web technologies."

- Has custom APIs (Node plugins) for building UI
- Sponsored by Intel

---

## [Thrust](http://enyojs.com/)

[image: GitHub stars]

"Chromium-based cross-platform / cross-language application framework.
Thrust is require/import-able, it lets you distribute NodeJS, Go or Python GUI apps directly through their native package managers."

- Language bindings allow you to use Node.js, Go, Python, or Scala as the backend

---

## [EnyoJS](http://enyojs.com/)

[image: GitHub stars]

"A framework for building native-quality HTML5 apps that work everywhere.
Use Enyo to develop apps for all major platforms, from phones and tablets
to PCs and TVs."

- Bundles everything into a package for installation.
- Developed by LG

---

See also:

- [**Technical** differences between Electron and NW.js](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/development/atom-shell-vs-node-webkit.md)
- [**Functional** differences among NW.js, Brackets-Shell, and Electron (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731517/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-node-webkit-brackets-shell-and-atom).

Answer (score 5):

#### [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)

1. It allows using

   - HTML 5,
   - CSS 3,
   - JavaScript (including NodeJS APIs!)
2. It packages all the content into one bundle.
3. It supports

   - Windows
   - Linux
   - Mac OS X